# installed Xubuntu 10.10 and now I can't start WIndows XP

Tags: windows-xp, multi-boot, xubuntu, wubi

I just installed Xubuntu 10.10 using wubi.exe on the install disk.
It didn't say anything about repartitioning hard disks or anything, but now Xubuntu runs, and WinXP doesn't. When I try to run Windows, I get STOP error 0x0000007B. Any ideas of anything I can do to get my files back?
Note: the error message is exactly the same as the one in [Windows XP Cant install STOP error 0x0000007B](https://superuser.com/questions/158784/windows-xp-cant-install-stop-error-0x0000007b)

**EDIT:** I tried booting windows again, and the STOP error changed from 7B to 24.
My parents took the computer into a repair shop, so I guess this is closed. I'm supposed to get it back on Monday. The only bad thing is that I'm paying the bills :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried booting windows again, and the STOP error changed from 7B to 24.
My parents took the computer into a repair shop, so I guess this is kind of closed. I'm supposed to get it back on Monday. The only bad thing is that I'm paying the bills :(

Answer (score 1):

Did you change anything in the BIOS?
Try changing the SATA settings in the BIOS to IDE-compatible mode (non-native SATA)...
Depending on your BIOS, Windows may access the drives either via SATA or IDE drivers, even if all your drives are SATA.
If Windows was installed while in IDE-compatible mode, and now the BIOS is set to pure SATA mode, you would get blue screen...

Comment: I didn't change anything, all I did was run wubi.exe, restart the computer and finish the Xubuntu install. Then Windows wouldn't boot.

Comment: no BIOS settings were changed, unless Xubuntu changed them. I went into the BIOS setup, though, and I didn't notice anything different.

Comment: Did you check if its in SATA or IDE mode?

Comment: It doesn't say anything about SATA or IDE mode, but all the setting labels start with IDE, and it says nothing about SATA, so I am assuming it's in IDE mode.