# Cannot install Ubuntu 11.10 with wubi

Tags: ubuntu, installation, wubi

I had a dualboot on my Dell 8400: Windows XP and Ubuntu 10.4. Windows no longer works. I got the blue screen of death, and I can no longer boot into Windows, but I can boot into Ubuntu.

I want to do a clean install of 11.10. I did a `sudo update-grub` and got this:

```
Searching for GRUB installation directory ... found: /boot/grub
Searching for default file ... found: /boot/grub/default
Testing for an existing GRUB menu.lst file ... found: /boot/grub/menu.lst
Searching for splash image ... none found, skipping ...
Found kernel: /boot/vmlinuz-2.6.32-36-generic
Found kernel: /boot/vmlinuz-2.6.32-35-generic
Found kernel: /boot/vmlinuz-2.6.32-34-generic
Found kernel: /boot/vmlinuz-2.6.32-33-generic
Found kernel: /boot/vmlinuz-2.6.32-32-generic
Found kernel: /boot/vmlinuz-2.6.32-31-generic
Found kernel: /boot/vmlinuz-2.6.32-30-generic
Found kernel: /boot/vmlinuz-2.6.32-29-generic
Found kernel: /boot/vmlinuz-2.6.32-28-generic
Found kernel: /boot/vmlinuz-2.6.32-27-generic
Found kernel: /boot/vmlinuz-2.6.32-26-generic
Found kernel: /boot/vmlinuz-2.6.31-20-generic
Found kernel: /boot/vmlinuz-2.6.28-18-generic
Found kernel: /boot/vmlinuz-2.6.27-17-generic
Found kernel: /boot/memtest86+.bin
Updating /boot/grub/menu.lst ... done
```

I'm having a hard time loading 11.10 from the CD and wubi.

I get to the installation part. I type in a new username and password and I get an error message

> cannot install into C:/ubuntu
>   there is another file with the same name

I don't mind that Ubuntu takes over the Windows partition, since I wasn't using it anyway.

Comment: [this happened to me](http://superuser.com/questions/260478/installed-xubuntu-10-10-and-now-i-cant-start-windows-xp)

Answer (score 1):

Install Ubuntu on the hard disk instead of using Wubi (since you don't use Windows it is better to go for an actual installation).

Answer (score 0):

As the error log mentions:

> Cannot install into C:\ubuntu. there is another file with the same name

Delete the Ubuntu folder before attempting to reinstall. **Note that doing this this will lead to your Ubuntu 10.04 boot from hard disk to fail.**